# Printing directly without displaying print dialogue box

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I have been trying to print the receipt through POS printer using Asp.net. But my code is running on local but unable to run on server(GoDaddy). Can anybody help me out to resolve it. I am using Print Class and predefined brush classes in asp .NET But while running on server the server is unable to revoke the printer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, any code that uses the print class will assume that the printer is physical attached to the computer running that software. (The web server in this case, and not the computer running the browser). This works on your development computer since that computer is also running the web server.

So, if you use hosting and not your development computer, then you will have to enter the GoDaddy server room and attach the printer to the web server such as like this:

[image]

A web browser can't mess around and start printing on MY computer running a browser anymore then such code can't use the windows message box command (that will run + appear on the server side and code system). So, a web browser can't steal my files, read my files, or use ANY resources on MY computer from a web browser.  The web browser can’t see or touch my folders, nor touch my printer, or anything else on my computer.
If a web browser could attach to my hardware, then the internet would not be secure and no one would use it.

So, printing from a web browser to a physical printer is not really much practical unless you have the end user use print from their browser, and then print to a physical printer attached

In most cases, it is recommended that you generate a PDF, and then display that PDF, and then the user can use the print option of that PDF. However, from a browser, you can't get any information about my computer, and my hardware and my printers. And the server can’t know if I have a printer attached, or that I just left your site and am now browsing on some other site.
You can build a client-side application that each user can install, and that windows program can then say call some web API and get the information from your web site and then send to the printer attached to my computer. This would not be browser-based code anymore, but a standard windows program that each user would have to install on their computers.